# html link for line break

Tags: html, css

---

Ok the topic I asked here is about "anchor" is that correct?

---

Ok this actually works now

`<a href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=363#tips1">**Development**</a>` this is on the First Site

And then where the Development is: (2nd site)

```
<a name="#tips1">**Developer**</a>
```

Did I miss something here?

---

Ok this is this first site:
http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa253/tintingerri/Test/test-4.png

Now if you can see, if you click on the "Development" it will go to the 2nd site. And in this 2nd site, this is where I listed the "Development" and "Consulting" in one page.

Now I would like that if the user click on "Consulting" it would go directly to the "Consulting" text and not to "Development" text first because they are written in one page.

So is this anchor?

Comment: What does this have to do with the tag 'linebreaks'? Do you want to go to an *external* site from those links, or to have those links cause hidden information to be shown (on the same page)?

Comment: @David: Sorry I don't understand your question...I was not sure what would be the title of my question because I don't know how to describe it maybe you could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#apple">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#banana">Banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="#grapes">Grapes</a></li>
</ul>
<hr />
<p id="apple">This is the Apple section.</p>
<hr />
<p id="banana">This is the Banana section.</p>
<hr />
<p id="grapes">This is the Grapes section.</p>
```

When you click on a link, it will take you to the section it's linked with via element IDs. The sections can be behind the `<hr />`.

Linking to another page is similar:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/fruit.html#apple">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fruit.html#banana">Banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fruit.html#grapes">Grapes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is this what you meant?

[EDIT]

After clearing the issue in the comments, the solution indeed turns out to be anchors. Page one, say, `index.html`, will have this code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/fruit.html#apple">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fruit.html#banana">Banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fruit.html#grapes">Grapes</a></li>
</ul>
```

While page two, say, `fruit.html`, will have this code:

```
<p id="apple">This is the Apple section.</p>
<hr />
<p id="banana">This is the Banana section.</p>
<hr />
<p id="grapes">This is the Grapes section.</p>
```

You don't have to use `<p>` tags, of course. You'll probably want to use `<div>` containers instead:

```
<div id="apple">
    <p>My apple stuff</p>
</div>
<hr />
```

etc.

Comment: @mingos: hmmm it's difficult to explain...How can I explain this simplier?... Yes I have a page where I write these points: Apple, Banana & Grapes. And they are clickable. And if you click on them, this will direct to another page, where you can see the information about Apple, Banana & Grapes. And after the info's of each, I separated it with <hr/>.

Comment: .... So that would be: Apple - Info Apple <hr/> Banana - Info Banana <hr/> Grapes - Info Grapes </hr> ... And in my first content, if the user clicks on Grapes, it should directly to the Grapes info, without seeing the Banana & Apple Info, but you can actually scroll it.

Comment: OK, then indeed this is what you're after. It's called anchors. You link to the other page with the `#idname` part (`/mysite.html#apple`). Then, on the `mysite.html` just create elements with corresponding IDs.

Comment: @mingos: the problem is it has the same id number because these Apple, banana & grapes are all in the same content

Comment: Why would the sections have the same ID? You can name your sections any way you like.

Comment: @mingos: please see my edited question & also my reply to David

Comment: I replied there. You're confusing an `id` variable passed via GET with an HTML ID.

Comment: what did you put in the `href`?

Comment: yes, you did miss something. The `href` in the 1st site does not specify the link to the 2nd one. It's supposed to be something like `href="http://www.example.com?id=123#apple"`. This means: load up `http://www.example.com?id=123` and find an element named "apple".

Comment: Try `<div id="tips1">**Developer**</div>` instead. The `<a name="...` AFAIK is invalid syntax in HTML5.

Comment: @mingos:Ok I tried the one you suggested but it didn't work. This one works now: <a href="http:site.com/index.php?id=363#job1">**Development**</a>

Comment: @mingos: and this is for the second site: <a name="job1">**Developer **</a>

Comment: Aye, in HTML4 it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @mingos: Check the site above and let me know what you think?

Comment: @mingos: I deleted it because we changed our minds. Now we came up with different ideas again. I think I better ask a new question for this. We will create another link for a particular section which doesn't appear on the site: if you can it here: http://www.securintegration.com/en/home/jobs.html

Comment: ...and if you click on the "mehr" it will open to a new content but I think the section is still the same which is under "job". I hope I am clear with my question. I would like to know how this is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure what you're asking here, but I get the impression it's along the lines of:

> If someone clicks the links, how do I show information related to that link on the same page?

Which is relatively easy:

#### html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#apple">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#banana">Banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="#grapes">Grapes</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="apple" class="panel">
<p>Apple Stuff</p>
</div>

<div id="banana" class="panel">
<p>Banana Stuff</p>
</div>

<div id="grapes" class="panel">
<p>Grapes Stuff</p>
</div>
```

#### css:

```
.panel {
    display: none;
}

.panel:target {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FjPKh/).

Comment: @David: I think this is what I want. But it has the same id number that is the problem.

Comment: @tintincute: an ID within an HTML document has to be *unique* they cannot be repeated, if you wish to repeat this, use a `class` instead.

Comment: The # character indicates that the href should take you to an element with a specific ID. Like, `href="#apple"` will take you to an element on the page with the attribute `id="apple"`.

Comment: @tintincute: the `#` is an anchor, or fragment identifier, in that it identifies a particular element (by its `id` or `name` (I think this may be deprecated, I'm not sure) value). What do you mean 'it has the same id number that is the problem'?

Comment: @David: this is what I got: <a href="http://site.com/index.php?id=363">**Development**</a>

Comment: .. and if I make this for Consulting : <a href="http://site.com/index.php?id=363">**Consulting**</a>

Comment: But how does that prevent you from using the anchor? The `id` in the link is passed via GET, most probably to fetch the content from the database. The HTML ID is something completely different and won't clash with the `id` variable

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to link to another place on your page?
For absolute, the following syntax is used: `<a href="web address">Link text</a>`.

With relative addressing, it is only necessary to use the name of the web page file you are linking to as the value in the href attribute provided that the page containing the link resides in the same folder as the page acting as the link's target.
Maybe still this doesnt answer your question?

For the same page, A named anchor inside an HTML document:

```
<a name="useful on same page">Useful Paragraph</a>
```

Create a link to the "Useful Paragraph" inside the same document:

```
<a href="#useful on same page">Useful Paragraph</a>
```

If I still havent answered the question, please provide more info

Comment: thanks for reply. But not sure what info should I provide more. Hmmm maybe I should create some screenshot..

Comment: Tintincute, "#" creates the id, so that it can be referenced elsewhere on the page, ie for using the link.

Comment: Yes this resolve my issue but I edited it because at first I overlook something. Check the link I got. See updated question above.

Answer (score 0):

With an ul, very simple:

```
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Grapes</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I know this. But what I would like to do is, that if the user click on those, it will go the site where Apple, Banana & Grapes are listed. The content of Apple, Banana & Grapes is written in 1 page only. So that the user will not scroll down & find the Banana & Grapes. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean ID's? Give the destination an id, like <div id="apple"> and then link to it with <a href="#apple">

Comment: I did it please see my updated question above. It didn't work.